# Select every div inside another div and check it's class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a chat system and I'm showing the messages using jQuery + JSON + PHP. My problem is: I have to select each div inside the div "#chatMessages", that contains the messages, and check it's class to see if it exists, my Ajax code:

```
    var data = {};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "../room/a.php",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.error) {
            alert(response.msg);
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i ++) {
                if($("#chatScreen > *").hasClass("message" + i) == false)
                $("#chatScreen").append($("<div>",{
                    class : 'message' + response[i][1],
                    html  : response[i][0] + ' ' + response[i][4]
                }));
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {

        },
    complete: function () {

        }
    });
```

`response[i][0]` contains the name, and the `response[i][4]` contains the message. It's working fine, but I load this function every 3000ms, so it repeat every message, how can I check div per div searching for the class `'message' + response[i][1]` (that contains the unique ID from MySQL)?

I tried to use ".hasClass()" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're performing `hasClass` on multiple elements, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, I just want to check if the message is already on the screen. It's in JSON format, so I think it's possible. I'll try with if($(".message" + i).length) {append}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if there's any element in the DIV with a given class, you can do:

```
if ($("#chatScreen").find(".message"+response[i][1]).length > 0) {
```

You can refactor it so you don't have to search for `#chatScreen` every time through the loop:

```
var chatScreen = $("#chatScreen");
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i ++) {
    if(chatScreen.find(".message"+response[i][1]).length > 0) {
        chatScreen.append($("<div>",{
            class : 'message' + response[i][1],
            html  : response[i][0] + ' ' + response[i][4]
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: @LcSalazar I almost wrote it that way, I decided to use the explicit `find` to make it clearer.

Comment: You can also omit the `> 0` comparison entirely if you want, since the number 0 is a falsy value - I sometimes leave the comparison in to be more explicit.

Comment: You can, but I don't like that in answers to questions, because it makes the intent less clear.